# Discord dm bot that can dm back by python

Tags: python

I wanna see the user's name, who sent me the message, how?

> I already wrote this..

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, user_id=None, *, args=None):
  if user_id is not None and args is not None:
    try:
        target = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
        await target.send(args)
        await ctx.channel.send("'" + args + "' has been sent to: " + target.name)

    except:
        await ctx.channel.send("I can't")

  else:
    await ctx.channel.send("Done")

@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
  if message.guild is None and not message.author.bot:
    print(message.content)
  await client.process_commands(message)
```

So what should I write?

Comment: Try `message.author.name`. If you have more than one person with the same name, you could use `message.author.discriminator` for the four-digit number at the end of the name. For a truly unique id, use `message.author.id`

Comment: Still not working!
I should put it here right `if message.guild is None and not message.author.id:`

Comment: What specifically is your problem?

Comment: It does not type the user's name, I cant know whos sending to me.

Comment: `message.author.id` is a number, hidden deep inside discord's code. Each discord account in the world has a different `id`. If you want the name of the user, use `message.author.name`. This author.name is a string of the name (not nickname) of the person who sent the message. Keep in mind that two people can have the same name, so you want to somehow combine the name with the four-digit number after it (`message.author.discriminator`) to greatly reduce the chance of having two people with the same name in your code. If you want to dm with someone, use `messsage.author.create_dm()`.

Comment: Please see the documentation: Message objects - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message , Member objects - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member , DM channel objects: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#dmchannel , All Discord Model objects - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-models . Please refer to this, to see if it can answer your problem.